# Migrate from couchDB to RDBMS

Tags: architecture, couchdb, rdbms

Wondering if it is possible to migrate from a document-based DB (eg. couchDB) to a RDBMS (eg. MySQL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes

The long Answer: the more features of an Document-DB (e.g. CouchDB) you use, the more pain you will feel. Concepts like complex map-reduce based "view" generation, complex, nested documents and the like don't map well to RDBMS.

Also thinks which are easy with CouchDB (Multi-Master with more than two Masters, Load balancing) are hard to nearly-impossible with RBMS.

On the other hand, applications which make heavy use of a real RDBMS (usually not mySQL) are much harder to port to CouchDB & friends, because they miss transactions and all the rest of the ACID properties. CouchDB provides much fewer guarantees in this regard. Therefore in general porting *from* couchdb is easier than porting *to* couchdb.

That said, many applications use RDBMS only as glorified (key, value) stores - these are easy to port in all directions.

Comment: hmmm, was under the impression going from couchdb -> rdbms would be straightforward. i'll have to look into that. thnx

Comment: We have several CouchDB applications which would take considerable effort to port to SQL. The couch views run a few hundred lines of javascript code in the "views" and uses CouchDB "triggers". All possible to emulate in SQL, but not easy.